# Session does not carry on

Tags: php, session, logging

I have an account.php page where the user has the ability to alter the account information saved on a mySQL database. When I click the link to it I get a message saying to "Go back and login before you visit this page!" My code is below.

pro.php (page directed to once logged in)

```
<?php

//STEP 1 Connect To Database
$connect = mysql_connect("Localhost","mlec2013_danny","8764963d");
if (!$connect)
{
die("MySQL could not connect!");
}

$DB = mysql_select_db('mlec2013_database');

if(!$DB)
{
die("MySQL could not select Database!");
}

//STEP 2 Declare Variables

$Name = $_POST['username'];
$Pass = $_POST['password'];
$Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='$Name' AND Password='$Pass'");
$NumRows = mysql_num_rows($Query);
$_SESSION['username'] = $Name;
$_SESSION['password'] = $Pass;

//STEP 3 Check to See If User Entered All Of The Information

if(empty($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['password']))
{
die("Go back and login before you visit this page!");
}

if($Name && $Pass == "")
{
die("Please enter in a name and password!");
}

if($Name == "")
{
die("Please enter your name!" . "</br>");
}

if($Pass == "")
{
die("Please enter a password!");
echo "</br>";
}

//STEP 4 Check Username And Password With The MySQL Database

if($NumRows != 0)
{
while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Query))
{
$Database_Name = $Row['username'];
$Database_Pass = $Row['password'];
}
}
else
{
die("Incorrect Username or Password!");
}


//end of PHP scripting. Information displayed below is in the form of HTML, CSS, or Javascript.
?>
```

account.php

```
<?php require_once('../../Connections/mySQL.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE Users SET first_name=%s, last_name=%s, mdcps_idnumber=%s, phone=%s, Username=%s, Password=%s, email=%s, class_code=%s WHERE id=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['first_name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['last_name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['mdcps_idnumber'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['phone'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Username'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Password'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['class_code'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_mySQL, $mySQL);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $mySQL) or die(mysql_error());

  $updateGoTo = "account.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
}

$colname_Recordset1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['Username'])) {
  $colname_Recordset1 = $_GET['Username'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_mySQL, $mySQL);
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordset1, "text"));
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $mySQL) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

$maxRows_DetailRS1 = 10;
$pageNum_DetailRS1 = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_DetailRS1'])) {
  $pageNum_DetailRS1 = $_GET['pageNum_DetailRS1'];
}
$startRow_DetailRS1 = $pageNum_DetailRS1 * $maxRows_DetailRS1;

$colname_DetailRS1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['recordID'])) {
  $colname_DetailRS1 = $_GET['recordID'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_mySQL, $mySQL);
$query_DetailRS1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Users  WHERE id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_DetailRS1, "int"));
$query_limit_DetailRS1 = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_DetailRS1, $startRow_DetailRS1, $maxRows_DetailRS1);
$DetailRS1 = mysql_query($query_limit_DetailRS1, $mySQL) or die(mysql_error());
$row_DetailRS1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($DetailRS1);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_DetailRS1'])) {
  $totalRows_DetailRS1 = $_GET['totalRows_DetailRS1'];
} else {
  $all_DetailRS1 = mysql_query($query_DetailRS1);
  $totalRows_DetailRS1 = mysql_num_rows($all_DetailRS1);
}
$totalPages_DetailRS1 = ceil($totalRows_DetailRS1/$maxRows_DetailRS1)-1;


//STEP 1 Connect To Database
$connect = mysql_connect("Localhost","mlec2013_danny","8764963d");
if (!$connect)
{
die("MySQL could not connect!");
}

$DB = mysql_select_db('mlec2013_database');

if(!$DB)
{
die("MySQL could not select Database!");
}

//STEP 2 Declare Variables

$Name = $_POST['username'];
$Pass = $_POST['password'];
$Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='$Name' AND Password='$Pass'");
$NumRows = mysql_num_rows($Query);
$_SESSION['username'] = $Name;
$_SESSION['password'] = $Pass;

//STEP 3 Check to See If User Entered All Of The Information
//STEP 4 Check Username And Password With The MySQL Database
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) at the beginning of your scripts.

Comment: Just a simple session_start() ?

Comment: Yes, session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

Comment: Thanks! Also do you know how I could get and echo the user's first name from the mySQL on the pro.php page?

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at your database structure, but look at how you are getting `$Database_Name`. Also, you will benefit from reading about [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) on any of your scripts? [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) needs to be used on ALL pages where sessions are being used / accessed. Make sure to use it BEFORE headers / output are send to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add `session_start()` right after opening the PHP tag in every document that uses sessions.